# Getting values from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I'm using *Mapquest* in an attempt to get latitude and longitude values of a requested address.

This is my call to their API:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=******&callback=renderOptions&outFormat=json&inFormat=json&json={location:{street:"Lancaster,PA"},options:{thumbMaps:false}}');

$output = json_decode($json, true);

$lat = $output['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lat'];
$lng = $output['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lng'];

echo $lat.",".$lng;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to echo the `LAT` and `LNG` to screen but it's empty. When I `print_r($json)`, I get the following:

> renderOptions({"results":[{"locations":[{"latLng":{"lng":-76.30127,"lat":40.03804},"adminArea4":"Lancaster
>   County","adminArea5Type":"City"...............

So I know the response is OK and that `LAT` and `LNG` are available, but if I `print_r($output)` I get nothing and if I `var_dump($output)` I get NULL, and obviously I don't get my LAT LNG data.

I'm not great with JSON and arrays. Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `&callback=renderOptions` from the URL. Right now, the server returns JSON**P** (with the specified callback function). This is no valid JSON and so `json_decode` returns `NULL` (as specified in the manual)

Comment: Thank you so much. I would never had guessed that, or if I did, it would be a week too late!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I honestly just know because I spent the last 2 weeks working with JSONP (until we decided to use sth else instead..)